# Pathfinding on Swift without Maps

Tags: swift, swift3, path-finding

I have a pathfinding problem to solve. I need to create an App, where you can go from one place to other place. My problem is, how can I make the an algorithm to solve a path on swift. I Already can know Where is the starting point and the end point, my issue is with the path. I need this app **Without** using Maps. This should be an image, Where I can somehow with some constraints (Walls) and some available Paths (Nodes) find the best route/path.
Something similar to what I want to achieve is on this image below..

[image]

I need to be able to select nodes to make routes and possible paths, and then make it give me the best path to follow.

I have seen [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html) And they have a great example using Grids, I need to solve this using Nodes instead.

Help would be much appreciated :D Maybe just some guidance, and hopefully some good implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Since it's an image, you need to have data about connections, walkways, walls, etc. then you can use a [pathfinding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding)

Comment: And how Can I load that data? You have any example? (I know its not a quite common problem)

Comment: This problem is about 1000x harder than you're making it out to be.

Comment: @BallpointBen never said it was easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH3-SW1) includes components for Pathfinding that can be used in any iOS App. The example for `Finding a Path in an Arbitrary Graph` might be relevant for your case and involves building a graph that represents the available paths in your image. The Pathfinding Algorithm is built into `GKGraph` and you can customise as required.

Comment: Thats sounds promising, you know any example, tutorial or something where I can see an implementation?

Comment: This [Tutorial](http://in8bits.com/gameplaykit-in-swift-a-tower-defence-game-part-3/) draws the path.

Comment: This [Video](https://realm.io/news/sash-zats-gameplaykit-beyond-games/) discusses using `GameplayKit` Pathfinding in an ordinary iOS App and shows how to setup the graph.

Comment: Thanks Mark, On the video they don't gave to much details on how to do it, you have other example?

Comment: This [Github](https://github.com/nuudles/NavigationMeshGraph) repo is a custom graph. To get started I would create a basic grid graph using the [GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH3-SW1) documentation and understand that each graph node represents a location on your image.

Comment: Thanks, Will take a look.
I have found this that is exactly what I need: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html But can't create my own maze! (It generate random Maze). Have you seen that Apple Example? If so, You know how can I create my own maze?

Comment: I think the important thing to understand is that a graph is a representation of a maze, map etc. so for your case you might imagine a 16x10 grid over your image, so each square in the grid becomes a graph node. You can build this graph using the example grid graph in Apple documentation, then remove nodes that can't be walked on.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly Why I need and what I thought. But Im having an issue on how to create my own "Maze" based on Apple example. Its the implementation on creating my own maze what is troubling me right now. In other Words, I don't understand the maze builder of the example, and how to edit it to create my own instead of a random maze.

Comment: Here's [another example](http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/demolition/page2-making-things-move). Keep in mind that you don't actually need to create a screen to explore Pathfinding, you could just draw the grid on paper and create a graph node to represent each square.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, The answer was the path that leads me to solve it, I finally used Apple Example and manage to make my own Map.

Comment: Hi There, me again, I have solved this using a grid, But I want to solve this using an Arbitrary path as you stated on you answer and as it shows on Apple Documentation. Do you have an example of that?

Comment: For the arbitrary path you can use `GKGraphNode` and `GKGraph` directly and determine yourself how the nodes are connected. You just need to know how each node represents a location on your screen. That's the arbitrary part. Another option is to subclass `GKGraph` to encapsulate this node creation, [this example](https://github.com/markbrownsword/hexagonal-map-intermediate/blob/master/src/HexGraph.swift) I made for pathfinding on an Hexagonal Map.